# .NET HTTP Client 4.0.0 is ignoring the DefaultRequestHeader value while a PostAsync request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` for my http `POST` request. I have a perfectly working code in .NET 6.0 (HTTP Client 6.0.0) in which I am passing my `DefaultRequestHeader.Add("Cookie", seesionID)`, but I need to do this same thing in my .NET 4.5 (Http client v4.0.0) project.

The code in .NET 4.5 is not not sending the cookie value with my request, and as a result, I get a "no authentication" error.

Is there any point I am missing while using Http client v4.0.0 ?

Comment: Normally, if you set a "Cookie" header, it is ignored, but that's because HttpClientHandler defaults to using its CookieContainer property for cookies. If you disable that, then by setting UseCookies to false, you can set cookie headers manually, and they will appear in the request